# Cloze question combining mchoice and num import in Moodle

Tags: r, moodle, r-exams

I created a cloze question combining mchoice and num. However I cannot import the question in Moodle as it says 
 **Error importing question Invalid embedded answers (Cloze) question (One of the answers should have a score of 100% so it is possible to get full marks for this question.).** 
If I turn it into a single mchoice question (deleting the num question) or I turn it into a single num chestion (deleting the mchoice part) it works. I could not find such an example on r-exams.org, that is why I turned here.

This is my Code:

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
library(exams)
Fragen=data.frame(
  Fragen=c(
    "Vergleich Schlachtgewicht (g) männlicher und weiblicher Hühner (Hähne/Hennen) der gleichen Linie.",
    "Untersuchung der Anzahl Insektenarten, welche auf unterschiedlichen Feldern vorkommen (Magerwiese, Klee, je 10 Felder).",
    "Untersuchung Sulfatgehalt (mg) bei Wasserproben aus der Limmat. Die Proben wurden an zwei unterschiedlichen Stellen entnommen (Limmatquai, Werdinsel, während 14 Tagen)",
    "Untersuchung Kürbisgewicht (kg) bei Düngung mit Gülle oder Kompost"),
  Stichprobe1=c("Hahn","Magerwiese","Limmatquai","Guelle"),
  Stichprobe2=c("Henne","Klee","Werdinsel","Kompost"),
  mean1=c(2500,50,250,10),
  mean2=c(2000,20,200,12),
  sd1=c(300,20,50,5),
  sd2=c(300,10,40,5),
  n=c(20,10,14,16)
)
n=sample(4,1)

## DATA
x1=abs(round(rnorm(Fragen$n[n],Fragen$mean1[n],Fragen$sd1[n])))
x2=abs(round(rnorm(Fragen$n[n],Fragen$mean2[n],Fragen$sd2[n])))
datadf=data.frame(x1,x2)
names(datadf)=c(as.character(Fragen$Stichprobe1[n]),as.character(Fragen$Stichprobe2[n]))
write.csv(datadf, "stichproben.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)

alpha=0.05
ps1=shapiro.test(x1)$p.value
ps2=shapiro.test(x2)$p.value
pf=var.test(x1,x2)$p.value
if (ps1 > alpha & ps2 > alpha) {
  if (pf > alpha) {
    p=t.test(x1,x2,var.equal = TRUE)$p.value
  }else{
    p=t.test(x1,x2,var.equal = FALSE)$p.value
  }
}else{
  p=wilcox.test(x1,x2)$p.value
}
p
msol=c(ps1>alpha & ps2>alpha, pf>alpha,TRUE)
msol
```

Question
========

`r Fragen$Fragen[n]`

Die Daten sind im File [stichproben.csv](stichproben.csv). 

Answerlist
----------
* Die Stichproben sind normalverteilt
* Die Varianzen sind homogen
* Die Stichproben sind unabhängig
* Führe den am besten geeigneten Test durch und kopiere den p-Wert ins Feld:

Solution
========

```{r solutionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}

```

Meta-information
================
exname: t-Test unabhaengig
extype: cloze
exsolution: `r mchoice2string(msol)`|`r format(p)`
exclozetype: mchoice|num
extol: `r format(0.01*p)`
````

Comment: I find it mildly irritating to find triple "backticks" (used as an alternative to `~~~` to bracket blocks as "code") and single ones (for `\`snippets\``) in a code block: can you comment (before the block) that this is intentional (and, e.g. `Die Daten sind im File` part of the code)?

Comment: I am sorry, I created this problem based on the examples that came with r-exams. I  do not understand.

Comment: Yes, this is standard R/Markdown syntax and completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### New answer (Edit: 2020-06-07)

Version 2.4-0 of R/exams has been improved for better support of `mchoice` elements in `cloze` questions. Running your `exams2moodle("stichproben.Rmd")` yields an exercise like this in Moodle:

[image: Moodle screenshot]

Caveat: By default this uses Moodle's evaluation rule for multiple-choice questions where each incorrect checkbox eliminates one correct checkbox. In principle, it is possible to change the `eval` rule in `exams2moodle()` but this does not work in all settings. Apparently, if the Moodle percentages only add up approximately but not exactly to 100%, they are not read correctly. My reading is that this is a bug in Moodle. See also below.

#### Old answer (2020-05-17)

Multiple-choice questions where multiple answers are correct are a bit tricky within Moodle cloze exercises. My understanding is that these were not actually allowed up to a certain point (see the discussion at https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=213016). Hence, we have only examples with cloze exercises containing single-choice elements but not multiple-choice-elements.

*[Note: Jargon is not unified across systems. "Single choice" in R/exams is called "multiple choice, single answer" in Moodle. And "multiple choice" in R/exams is called "multiple choice, multiple answer" in Moodle. Here, I use the shorter jargon as employed by R/exams.]*

Actually, I thought that Moodle still didn't support multiple-choice questions as elements in cloze exercises. This would also be consistent with the error message you got, requesting exactly one correct answer yielding 100%.

However, it turns out that under certain conditions it actually works. First, you need to choose a `MULTIRESPONSE` rather than `MULTICHOICE` type in `exams2moodle()` (i.e., this could be fixed on the R/exams side). Second, the percentages of the correct answers needs to sum to *exactly* 100%. Unfortunately, this conflicts with Moodle requiring `33.33333%` as the input for 1/3 of the points. I didn't find a solution to this - other than avoiding the situation where exactly three answers are correct.

As an example I copied your code above into a file `stichproben.Rmd` and then ran:

```
set.seed(77)
exams2moodle("stichproben.Rmd", name = "stichproben", cloze = list(
  cloze_mchoice_display = "MULTIRESPONSE",
  eval = list(partial = TRUE, rule = "false2")
))
```

Note that the seed is important as it leads to only two out of three items in the multiple-choice question being correct. The `eval` rule is chosen such that 50% of the points are subtracted if the incorrect item is chosen. This all works as intended in Moodle.

However, running the code above using `set.seed(1)` before, leads to all three items in the multiple-choice question being correct. Then I still get the error message quoted in your question and - as pointed out above - I don't know if/how this can be avoided. I didn't find a solution. Hence, personally, I would rather avoid `mchoice` elements in `cloze` questions and use several `schoice` elements instead.

Comment: @Matthias I think I found a solution to work around the problems you had automatically. Please install the devel version from R-Forge and try to process your exercise with this: `install.packages("exams", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Comment: thank you. That works fine! I also solved the problem with multiple-choice questions where none is true by adding a choice that is always true or by adding the choice "none of the other statements is true".

Comment: In such cases I typically put `ok <- FALSE` at the beginning of the R code chunk and then wrap everything into `while(!ok) { ... }`. And the `ok` condition at the end could be something like `ok <- sum(msol) > 0` or something similar...

Comment: Thanks. That is obviously mor ellegant.

Comment: @AchimZeileis I imported this exercise in my moodle environment, got this error: "Error importing question Invalid embedded answers (Cloze) question (One of the answers should have a score of 100% so that it is possible to get the maximum score on this question.)." (translation from Spanish) This is to blame to my moodle version? is there any workaround?

Comment: This is the error that occurred with older versions of R/exams but that should have been fixed in the current development version. When I install R/exams from R-Forge (see the first comment above), then I get `packageDescription("exams")[["Repository/R-Forge/DateTimeStamp"]]`: 2022-07-09 01:50:15. Using this version it is no problem to import the output of `exams2moodle("stichproben.Rmd")` into Moodle.