# Grading multiple choice and cloze questions created with exams2moodle()

Tags: r, moodle, r-exams

I am using `exams2moodle()` from R/exams to create multiple choice and cloze questions in Moodle. Before preparing exams, I would like to be certain how Moodle computes grades.

It seems to me that in multiple choice questions the default setting in the evaluation policy is `partial = TRUE, rule = "false", negative = FALSE`. Is that correct?

For the cloze questions, it seems that the overall grade assigned to the cloze question is divided equally among the subquestions. I wonder if there is some way to give unequal weight to the single sub-questions.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Let me know if the information contained in the below comment resolved your issue.  If it did, please select the answer to close out the question.  Best wishes!

Comment: Not quite. My question was about Moodle behaviour in a single multiple choice question and also about how the R package "exams" interacts with Moodle (also with cloze questions).

Comment: I realize that the first part of my question can be partially answered looking at the documentation of the package "exams": rdocumentation.org/packages/exams/versions/2.3-4/topics/… If I understand correctly, the default is "rule=false" and "negative=false". I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Overview

Essentially you are correct. However, I will discuss a few details below that are Moodle-specific because Moodle does not support the full flexibility of the `exams_eval()` strategies from R/exams.

#### Multiple-choice (`mchoice`) questions

- Moodle only supports evaluations with partial credits and thus setting `partial = FALSE` is not possible.
- The evaluations in Moodle are always such that *not* ticking a box yields zero points. Only ticking a box can yield points (positive or negative).
- Ticking a correct box always gives the proportion 1/#ncorrect of the overall number of points were #ncorrect is the number of correct answer alternatives.
- Ticking an incorrect box can give a negative amount of points. The precise amount is controlled by the `rule` specification. For `rule = "false"` an incorrectly ticked box gives the proportion -1/#incorrect = -1/(n - #ncorrect).
- As this is pretty harsh in the case of exactly one incorrect alternative (ticking it erases all points), there is `rule = "false2"` which is the default. An incorrectly ticked box still subtracts the proportion 1/#incorrect except in the case where #incorrect = 1 when 1/2 is subtracted.
- The overall amount of points from all boxes combined cannot become negative! It may be displayed as negative in some situations but is actually treated as 0. Thus, the R/exams argument `negative = TRUE` would be ignored, it is implicitly always `negative = FALSE`.
- Because only ticking correct answer alternatives can yield positive points, there needs to be at least one correct answer alternative. If a multiple-choice question without correct answer alternatives is used, it always yields zero points.

#### Single-choice (`schoice`) questions

- Essentially, the same rules as above apply. The main difference is that Moodle uses radio buttons (rather than check boxes) for single-choice questions. Thus, participants can only select one alternative and not several ones.
- The other important difference is that the sum of points can become negative! (Unlike for multiple-choice questions.)
- `exams2moodle()` currently uses the same default evaluation strategy `rule = "false2"` for single-choice questions. This assures that the expected number of points from random guessing strategies is zero. (However, we are thinking about changing the default to `rule = "none"` which seems to be more commonly used, i.e, selected an incorrect alternative just gives zero points.)

#### Cloze questions

- The different parts of a cloze questions are evaluated separately and then simply summed up.
- For `schoice` or `mchoice` items within a cloze question, the same rules as above apply. Thus, points can become negative for single-choice questions but not for multiple-choice questions. The default is, however, not to use negative points.
- Note also that `mchoice` items within a cloze are currently not supported very well by R/exams because they were not supported at all by Moodle until recently. See [Cloze question combining mchoice and num import in Moodle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844322/cloze-question-combining-mchoice-and-num-import-in-moodle) We hope to improve this in future versions.
- By default the overall number of points is split equally among the items within a cloze. However, `expoints` can be set to a vector of the same length as the number of items giving the number of points for each. (This was improved in version 2.4-0, though.)

#### Marks

The assignment of marks to the points achieved cannot be controlled from `exams2moodle()` in R/exams. Thus, you have to configure this in Moodle when putting together the quiz there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed answer! I tried to use the option `schoice =list(eval=list(rule="none"))` but I get the error message "invalid argument type". Can you please tell me what I should write?

Comment: You currently need to write: `schoice = list(eval = list(partial = TRUE, rule = "none"))`. This is a bit awkward and should probably be improved in `schoice`. But at least it should do what you want...

Comment: for mchoice there is no mention of rule ```all```, documentation say " "all" uses 1 (so that a single wrong selection cancels all correct selections)" I am doing some test in moodle and I don't get this behavior. For example, a mchoice question with 5 options and one of them being correct. If I select the correct and any other I get a score of 0,75/1,00

Comment: Is this plain mchoice? This works for me as intended, e.g., `set.seed(1)` and then `exams2moodle("ttest.Rmd", mchoice = list(eval = exams_eval(rule = "all")))`. For mchoice in cloze questions you need at least version 2.4-0 of the package (the current development version from R-Forge). I had not stated this in the post before but corrected it now.