# r exams controlling the points for incorrect answers

Tags: r-exams

I was checking some examples of single choice and multiple choice for example swisscapital.Rmd and switzerland.Rmd. When running exams2moodle() and checking some parameters I found that incorrect answers are penalized with negative points (`<answer fraction="-25" format="html">` in swisscapital.Rmd for example). Is there a way to change this to 0 points for incorrect answers?

outoput of

```
exams2moodle("swisscapital.Rmd", n = 1, name = "swiss_test",
             encoding = "UTF-8",
             dir = "output",
             edir = "exercises")
```

is the `swiss_test.xml` file with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quiz>


<question type="category">
<category>
<text>$course$/swiss_test/Exercise 1</text>
</category>
</question>


<question type="multichoice">
<name>
<text> Q1 : swisscapital </text>
</name>
<questiontext format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
<p>What is the seat of the federal authorities in Switzerland (i.e., the de facto capital)?</p>
</p>]]></text>
</questiontext>
<generalfeedback format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
<p>There is no de jure capital but the de facto capital and seat of the federal authorities is Bern.</p>
<ol type = "a">
<li> False </li>
<li> False </li>
<li> False </li>
<li> True </li>
<li> False </li>
</ol>
</p>]]></text>
</generalfeedback>
<penalty>0</penalty>
<defaultgrade>1</defaultgrade>
<shuffleanswers>false</shuffleanswers>
<single>true</single>
<answernumbering>abc</answernumbering>
<answer fraction="-25" format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
Lausanne
</p>]]></text>
<feedback format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
False
</p>]]></text>
</feedback>
</answer>
<answer fraction="-25" format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
Basel
</p>]]></text>
<feedback format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
False
</p>]]></text>
</feedback>
</answer>
<answer fraction="-25" format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
St. Gallen
</p>]]></text>
<feedback format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
False
</p>]]></text>
</feedback>
</answer>
<answer fraction="100" format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
Bern
</p>]]></text>
<feedback format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
True
</p>]]></text>
</feedback>
</answer>
<answer fraction="-25" format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
Geneva
</p>]]></text>
<feedback format="html">
<text><![CDATA[<p>
False
</p>]]></text>
</feedback>
</answer>
</question>

</quiz>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [help of exams2moodle](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/exams/versions/2.3-6/topics/exams2moodle):

> **rule**: character specifying which rule to use for negative partial
> credits. see function exams_eval

In the [exams_eval](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/exams/versions/2.3-6/topics/exams_eval):

> and "none" uses 0 (so that wrong selections have no effect at all)

So you should do:

```
exams2moodle(..., schoice = list(eval = exams_eval(rule = "none")))
```

See also [Grading multiple choice and cloze questions created with exams2moodle()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153575/grading-multiple-choice-and-cloze-questions-created-with-exams2moodle) for more details.

Comment: I got ```Error in rmarkdown::pandoc_convert(input = infile, output = outfile, from = from,  : 
  unused argument (eval = list("none"))``` i think the correct sintax is ```exams2moodle(...,rule="none")``` since in fact ```eval``` is not a parameter of ```exams2moodle```

Comment: I have read the help, however it is not clear for me how to use ```exams_eval``` in ```exams2moodle```

Comment: The `eval` argument needs to be passed to `schoice` only, it's not a direct argument for `exams2moodle()`. I've also added a link to a more detailed discussion of grading in `exams2moodle()` which covers this among other stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it, I hurried it.